# Error in sending principal to kerberos server. Apache2 and kerberos5

Tags: kerberos, apache2.4

When i try to authenticate through apache2 with kerberos5 i get an error.
i use mod_auth_kerb
when i look to my apache logs i can see my principal modified by adding:
.0.16.172.in-addr.arpa@ at the end.
so kerberos answer with

> failed to verify krb5 credentials: Server not found in Kerberos database

i am able to get a ticket from kerberos

i use keytab with an random key to authenticate my server:  HTTP/admin-apache.domain.com
here an extract of apache logs :

> [Wed Apr 15 16:12:50.539355 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 30467]
>   mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.90.100:43211] AH01626:
>   authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated
>   user yet)
>   [Wed Apr 15 16:12:50.539412 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid
>   30467] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.90.100:43211] AH01626:
>   authorization result of : denied (no authenticated user
>   yet)
>   [Wed Apr 15 16:12:50.539440 2015] [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 30467]
>   src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1971): [client 192.168.90.100:43211]
>   kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
>     [Wed Apr 15 16:12:50.541680 2015] [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 30467]
>   src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1049): [client 192.168.90.100:43211] Using
>   HTTP/admin-apache.domain.com.0.16.172.in-addr.arpa@ as server
>   principal for password verification
>   [Wed Apr 15 16:12:50.541715 2015]
>   [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 30467] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(753): [client
>   192.168.90.100:43211] Trying to get TGT for user mope@domain.com
>   [Wed Apr 15 16:12:50.565806 2015] [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 30467]
>   src/mod_auth_kerb.c(663): [client 192.168.90.100:43211] Trying to
>   verify authenticity of KDC using principal
>   HTTP/admin-apache.domain.com.0.16.172.in-addr.arpa@
>     [Wed Apr 15> 16:12:50.575915 2015] [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 30467]
>   src/mod_auth_kerb.c(678): [client 192.168.90.100:43211]
>   krb5_get_credentials() failed when verifying KDC
>   [Wed Apr 15 16:12:50.575946 2015] [auth_kerb:error] [pid 30467] [client
>   192.168.90.100:43211] failed to verify krb5 credentials: Server not found > in Kerberos database
>   [Wed Apr 15 16:12:50.575959 2015]
>   [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 30467] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1131): [client
>   192.168.90.100:43211] kerb_authenticate_user_krb5pwd ret=401 user=(NULL) authtype=(NULL)

here my config of vhost:

> ```
>  ServerName ldapadmin.domain.com  
>  ServerAdmin root@localhost  
>  DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpldapadmin/htdocs  
>  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ldap.localhost-error.log  
>  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ldap.localhost-access.log common    </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> AuthType Kerberos
>   AuthName "domain.com"
>   KrbMethodNegotiate on
>   KrbMethodK5Passwd on
>   Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/http.keytab
>   KrbAuthRealms DOMAIN.COM
>   KrbServiceName  HTTP
>   Require valid-user
>
> ```
> DirectoryIndex index.php
> Options +FollowSymLinks
> AllowOverride None
>
> Order allow,deny
> Allow from all
>
> <IfModule mod_mime.c>
>
>   <IfModule mod_php5.c>
>     AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
>
>     php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
>     php_flag track_vars On
>     php_flag register_globals Off
>     php_value include_path .
>   </IfModule>
>
>   <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
>     <IfModule mod_actions.c>
>       <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
>         AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
>         Action application/x-httpd-php /cgi-bin/php5
>       </IfModule>
>       <IfModule mod_cgid.c>                                                    
>         AddType application/x-httpd-php .php                                   
>         Action application/x-httpd-php /cgi-bin/php5                           
>        </IfModule>
>     </IfModule>
>   </IfModule>
>
> </IfModule>
> ```

Why my principal is modified by apache ?
What can i do for fix this ?
Thanks for your help
Be nice i am a beginner in Kerberos5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid this kind of error. you have to check your DNS records.
check the reverse lookup.
With bind9 you must check the records of your domain.
The syntax is a usual source of mistakes
It must have a "." at the end of each record in the file db.xx.xx.xx.in-addr.arpa

Comment: Can you add a bit more details? What needs to be checked exactly?